# Why global is null in function?

Tags: php

I get this strange problem....

All the page has this code only.
global $currentPage; is null and i dont know why...

```
<?php
$pager = $_PARAMS["this"];
$pages = 5;
$currentPage = 1;
$tst="ap";
$nearPages = 5;
//Prologic
?>
<div class="pager">
<?php
$nearPagesHalf = ($nearPages - 1) / 2;

drawNumbers(1, 1);
if ($currentPage - $nearPagesHalf <= 0) {

}

drawNumbers($pages, $pages);
?> 

    <?php

    function drawNumbers($from, $to) {
        global $currentPage;



        for ($i = $from; $i <= $to; $i++) {

            echo $currentPage;

            if ($i == $currentPage) {
    ?> <span class="pageNumbers current"><?= $i ?></span>

    <?php
            } else {
    ?>
                <a href="#">
                    <span class="pageNumbers"><?= $i ?></span>
                </a>
<?php
            }
        }
?>
    <?php
    }

    function drawDots($from, $to) {

    }
    ?>

</div>
```

THE PROBLEM

```
echo $currentPage; prints 1 
        function drawNumbers($from, $to) {
            global $currentPage;
           echo $currentPage; prints nothing
```

Comment: If it is the only code of one page then how this `$pager = $_PARAMS["this"];` supposed to work?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I bet you're executing this code by including this file inside another function.

So you need to mark the first variable occurrence as `global` too.

Btw, global variables are weird, the more simple and correct way to pass the data to the function is to use function parameters.

Comment: @Parhs: then mark the first variable as global too: `global $currentPage = 1;`. But anyway - this solution is terrible. As well as `eval()` is terrible.

Comment: I hate globals too but the framework which i am forced to use is composed of many globals!

Comment: @BoltClock each page while executing php is evaled!Is that too bad? I wouldnt do something like that but i cant say exactly why it is bad

Comment: @Parhs: it is very bad ;-) it is terrible slow, it is difficult to maintain/develop/debug/etc

Comment: Global is weird but of course it exists for a reason. I have a case in which i cannot access the global var to pass it through the rest of the system execution using parameters, unless i kick away the design pattern and good practices. The only solution is the global var declaration.

Answer (score 5):

The `$currentPage` defined at the top does not live in `global` space. Why don't you just pass the `$currentPage` as the first parameter to the drawNumbers function? It's much cleaner that way:

```
drawNumbers( $currentPage, 1, 1 );

function drawNumbers($currentPage, $from, $to) {
// no need define $currentPage here since it's passed
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, but the solution is not on this page so I am putting here in order to help anyone who might show up looking.

My global variable was an object and it worked fine when calling the global vairable from a method AFTER the variable was defined.

```
class object{

    function __construct($v1, $v2){

    }

    function methodA(){
        global $a;
        var_dump($a);
    }
}
$a = new object($var1, $var2);
$a->methodA(); //Object...
```

However, when trying to use the global variable before the constructor has return it does not work.

```
 class object{

    function __construct($v1, $v2){
        $this->methodA();//NULL
    }

    function methodA(){
        global $a;
        var_dump($a);
    }
}
$a = new object($var1, $var2);
```

This looks like a dunce-cap situation, but my site is a lot more complex than this simplified scenario. So it took me a while to figure out that I was calling it before it was defined.